# Ajax Handling Database Errors

Tags: php, ajax

This may be more of an opinion based answer but I would like to know which method is more efficient/faster for handling database errors through an ajax call.  Both of these errors would be handled in the success function of the ajax call.

method 1:

```
<?php
header("dberror:" . $errormsg );
exit();
?>
```

method 2:

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array("dberror" => $errormsg));
?>
```

Comment: It isn't so much a matter of opinion, but (a) is something that you can easily benchmark for yourself and (b) there is unlikely to be any significant difference between the two options (at least as far as efficiency and performance are concerned).

Answer (score 0):

for example i dont show any errors on JSON i simply do a transaction message is success or had an error example

```
  { "transaction":"success" }

  { "transaction":"error" }
```

and also you need to setup a json header.

```
 header('application/json');

 echo json_encode($json_string);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the json method is better for parsing. With jquery you can do an ajax call specially for json. The call is $.getJSON (). I have never seen to return an error as header ...